# Object not set as an instance of an object in rhino mocks

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, mocking, nunit

update: 3

I am trying to mock out a method that a class uses to create new instances of other classes through unit of work. When I try and mock the method to return fixed data i get a null instead of the list when the getPage method has been called.

here is my code

```
[TestFixture()]
public class CustomerServiceTests
{
    private ICustomerService service;
    private IUnitOfWork mockUnitOfWork;
    private IGenericRepository<Entities.Customer> repository;

    private int customerId;
    private int ContactId;

    [SetUp()]
    public void Setup()
    {
        customerId = 1;
        ContactId = 1;
    }

  [Test()]
    public void GetCustomers_should_return_three_results()
    {
        mockUnitOfWork = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IUnitOfWork>();
        repository = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IGenericRepository<Entities.Customer>>();

        List<Entities.Customer> customerList = new List<Entities.Customer>
        {
            new Entities.Customer { Id = 1, CompanyName = "test1", ContractorId = 1 },
            new Entities.Customer { Id = 2, CompanyName = "test2", ContractorId = 2 },
            new Entities.Customer { Id = 3, CompanyName = "test3", ContractorId = 1 },
            new Entities.Customer { Id = 4, CompanyName = "test4", ContractorId = 1 },
            new Entities.Customer { Id = 5, CompanyName = "test5", ContractorId = 4 }
        };


        var IQueryableList = customerList.AsEnumerable();            
        mockUnitOfWork.Stub(uow => uow.CustomerRepository).Return(repository);




        repository.Stub(repo => repo.GetPaged()).Return(new ContentList<Entities.Customer> { List = IQueryableList, Total = customerList.Count });

        service = new CustomerService(mockUnitOfWork);

        var resultList = service.GetCustomers(new PageRequest {PageSize = 20, PageIndex = 1 });
        var total = resultList.Data.Total;
        Assert.AreEqual(10, total);
    }
```

The part of the service code returns null instead of the list supplied.

```
            customers = _service.CustomerRepository.GetPaged(filter, orderBy, pageRequest.PageSize, pageRequest.PageIndex, "CustomersContacts");
```

Comment: What type is service in your updated code?

Comment: Thats customerService. Its the method i am running my test through.

Comment: Can you add more code to show how you're creating your customerService? I think I might know the issue.

Comment: i have included the customer service code setup in update 2.

Comment: Are you still getting a NullReferenceException? When I run this (although my implementation might be different) I get a test failure of:
  Expected: 10
  But was:  5

Comment: I have updated my code. The line in the customerService returns a null instead of the i told to return.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You set up a stub for GetPaged without parameters

```
GetPaged()
```

But you're calling GetPaged with parameters

```
GetPaged(filter, orderBy, pageRequest.PageSize, pageRequest.PageIndex, "CustomersContacts")
```

Try something like this (you'll need to verify the syntax, making sure it's the right types)

```
repository
    .Stub(repo => repo.GetPaged(
        Arg<string>.Is.Anything, 
        Arg<string>.Is.Anything,  
        Arg<int>.Is.Anything, 
        Arg<int>.Is.Anything, 
        Arg<string>.Is.Anything))
    .Return(new ContentList<Entities.Customer> { List = IQueryableList, Total = customerList.Count });
```